# Image of the tensor product of strict maps of Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to D$ be bounded linear maps of Banach spaces with closed image. Will $f\widehat{\otimes}g:A\widehat{\otimes}_\pi B\to C\widehat{\otimes}_\pi D$ also have closed image? What about injective tensor products?

Comment: What is the notation $\hat{\otimes}_\pi$?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: it is called projective tensor product (you can start from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the first question let $A$ be a closed subspace of $C$ and $B$ be a closed subspace of $D$. Let $f$ and $g$ be natural embeddings. Then OP's question is equivalent to the following: does projective tensor product respect embeddings? It is not, see [*Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals. A. Defant, K. Floret*](http://bookfi.org/book/1113022) page 36, section 3.9

Now we move to the second question. Let $C$ be a quotient of $A$, and $B$ be a quotient of $D$. Assume $f$ and $g$ are respective quotient maps. Then OP's question may be formulated as follows: does injective tensor product respect quotients? Again it is not, see the same book page 49, section 4.3