# Ideals and exactness of projective tensor product of Banach spaces / algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, banach-algebras

Thanks for suggesting this question: [Image of the tensor product of strict maps of Banach spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487127/image-of-the-tensor-product-of-strict-maps-of-banach-spaces)
I read the reference and realize that for a short exact sequence of Banach algebra:
$0 \to J \to A \to A/J \to 0$
only makes sense if $J \to A$ has closed image. So in general $D \otimes_\pi$ will not preserve that.

So my new question is:
It seems to me that it is hard enough to be a closed subspace. Is there any reference on the ideals of projective tensor product of Banach algebras? Better if examples of computation is available. Thanks!

Comment: computation of what?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I meant more examples about how to work with them. I guess I will look more closely at the reference and see if I have any specific questions. One reference that I found very helpful is: Raymond A. Ryan's Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces

Answer (score 1):

General description of ideals of tensor products of Banach algebras is hopeless, so the only thing is consideration of some important cases. Here is what I found

[Maximal ideals in tensor products of Banach algebras Arnold Lebow](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183529956)

[Maximal two-sided ideals in tensor  products of Banach algebras Kjeld. B. Laursen](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2036625?uid=3738936&uid=366144821&uid=2&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21103285950827)

[Primitive ideals in tensor product of Banach algebras Jun Tomiyama](http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/math/article/viewFile/11081/9102)

If you will not restrict yourself only with projective tensor product, you can take a look at the

[Ideals in Operator Space Projective Tensor Product of $C^*$-algebras. Ranjana Jain, Ajay Kumar](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3143)

It contains a lot of references to the similar question for Haagerup and minimal tensor product of $C^*$-algebras. In fact minimal tensor product of $C^*$-algebras is much more important than others becuase it relates different nice properties such as exactness, nuclearity and ameanability. For details see section IV.3 in

[Operator algebras. Theory of C-star-algebras and von Neumann algebras. B. Blackadar](http://carlossicoli.free.fr/B/Blackadar_B.-Operator_algebras._Theory_of_C-star-algebras_and_von_Neumann_algebras_%28bad_p480%29-Springer%282006%29.pdf)